# Why does the element overlay blinks?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add an overlay to a div when the mouse hovers it. Althought it works, the overlay keeps blinking while I move the mouse inside the the div.
How can I prevent this?

**HTML:**

```
<div id="d4" class="dmc_block" style="width:60%; background:#eee; z-index:1">
    <div style="padding:20px;">
        <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','.dmc_block',function(){
    var o = $(this).offset();
    var h = $(this).height();
    var w = $(this).width();
    $('<div>').addClass('hover').css({width:w,height:h,left:o.left,top:o.top,position:'absolute',zIndex:2}).insertAfter(this);
}).on('mouseleave','.dmc_block',function(){
    $('.hover').remove();
});    
$('body').on('mouseenter','.hover',function(){return false;});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9Lhw/

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code here? Also `<blink>` FTW!

Comment: use `:hover` pseudo class instead.

Comment: Add the code to the question next time please http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/118392/186879

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
.on('mouseleave','.dmc_block',function(){
```

To this:

```
.on('mouseleave','.hover',function(){
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/T9Lhw/3/)

When the overlay `.hover` is placed above `.dmc_block`, it triggers the `mouseleave` of `.dmc_block` as it is now below the `.hover`. What you want is the `mouseleave` of `.hover`.